# SASS - Referencing parent selector with @at-root in loop

Tags: sass

I have a problem that I cannot understand. When I'm trying to remove parent selector with @at-root rule nothing changes in sass selector output.

```
.contact {
    // Define first.
    $styles: one, two, three;

    // Mixins.
    @import 'styles/mixins';

    // Import placeholders.
    @import 'styles/style-one/base';
    @import 'styles/style-two/base';
    @import 'styles/style-three/base';

    // Loop through each style.
    @each $style in $styles {
        @at-root .form-style-#{$style}#{&} {
            @extend %style-#{$style};
        }
    }
}
```

I'm expecting output like this:

```
.form-style-three.contact .field { border-color:#2d2d37 }
```

but instead of code above, I'm getting selector like this:

```
.contact .form-style-three.contact .field { border-color:#2d2d37 }
```

Am I missing something here? Is it loop that is causing this issue?

```
node-sass       4.13.0  (Wrapper)       [JavaScript]
libsass         3.5.4   (Sass Compiler) [C/C++]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer: https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/b0083f2459cadbbd787331e8d8e63976

you have to add @at-root rule to imported placeholders, not to the rules in loop.